# How to wait until a value becomes added to ConcurrentDictionary or timeout occurs?

Tags: c#, multithreading, data-structures

I have a task that should wait until a value has been added to a ConcurrentDictionary. If the value is added, it should stop waiting and continue its work. It should stop waiting as well if a timeout occured (5 seconds for example).

The value should be added to the ConcurrentDictionary by another thread/task, however, due to the nature of the code, I do not want the threads to communicate with each other.

How I should go about implementing this (in C#) ?

Btw I am using Tasks, not Threads for most of the part, and thus I am not sure if Thread.Sleep or other methods on the current Thread would be a good decision, cause it might sleep other tasks which use the same thread and cause random problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think "waiting" for an element to be added to a collection is generally a bad thing.  Doing this, in general, means that a thread is blocked for some period of time.  If it's even possible, you then have to deal with timeouts.  If it's not possible to detect timeouts then you have to deal with aborting the thread to abort the wait (you never want to get into a situation where a thread is blocked indefinitely) e.g. cancellation.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is thread safe in and of itself; but this doesn't make *all* code that uses `ConcurrentDictionary` thread safe.  The application-specific thread-safety requirements need to still be taken into account when using a `ConcurrentDictionary` object.  `ConcurrentDictionary` cannot possibly implement those types of things.  What to do when a value is added to the dictionary is also very similar--the overhead of waiting or notifying external code upon new value additions would cause all usages of `ConcurrentDictionary` to be slower, even those usages that don't need to wait or don't need to be notified--so things like that are not implemented.  The fact that an application adds a value *and* needs to be notified that a value *was* added is probably pretty rare (from the dictionaries point of view, why would it tell *you* that *you* just added a value...).  So, that sort of application-specific thing is normally done at the application level.  i.e. the fact that a concurrent dictionary is used is a coincidence and your application notifies other threads that another thread has done something they need to know about.  This could mean wrapping adds to a dictionary instance with calls to `ManualResetEventSlim.Reset`/`Set` and something can wait with a `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait` override.  Or, it could simply be a matter of writing an event that gets raised whenever a value is added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `ConcurrentDictionary` provides any hooks for things like this.

You could *potentially* either wrap or derive from `ConcurrentDictionary` to provide this, but I'd be nervous of doing so.

The low-tech alternatively is simply to poll - loop round, checking and then sleeping, until you either find the right value or time out. It's far from great from an efficiency point of view, but it's probably the simplest approach if it doesn't give you any other problems.

Comment: yeah, wrapping around it could cause additional trouble I want to avoid. I am worried from poll-loop because I am using tasks, sleeping a thread could potentially cause both the producer and consumer task to sleep simultineously if they're on the same thread causing a deadlock :/

Comment: @xander: Polling would cause no more of a deadlock than a type-provided wait. In both cases you'd just have two sleeping tasks. How is that a deadlock?

Comment: I am not sure if it would be a deadlock, but if both are asleep then the producer won't be able to place the value in the dictionary and it would timeout anyway ? Also I don't want several tasks to be sleep for the timeout period which could be long (~5 sec+). What I think would be optimal is something like task.Sleep which wouldn't affect the other running tasks.

Comment: @xander: It sounds like you need to think more carefully about your requirements. How could this *possibly* work to avoid both of them waiting at the same time? Imagine you had the perfect method to do this - then work out what difference you *really* foresee with the polling version.

Answer (score -1):

This is how the sleep polling could work.  Quick and dirty. :)

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string,string> dic = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>();

int timeoutCount = 0;
bool hasTimedOut = false;
while (!dic.ContainsKey("KeyYouAreLookingFor"))
{
    //5 minutes has expired
    if (timeoutCount >= 10)
    {
        hasTimedOut = true;
        break;
    }

    //30 second sleep or whatever you want your poll time to be
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
    timeoutCount++;
}

if (hasTimedOut)
{
    //TODO: timeout code
}
else
{
    //TODO: Key has been added
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, you sure this won't cause trouble because I am using tasks instead of threads ? afaik a thread can handle multiple tasks. It couldn't be the case that both the waiting and the adding tasks be on the same thread, and thus both sleep creating a deadlock ?

Comment: Then you've got the problem of what to do with a thread that's blocked for 30 seconds.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks) is a good link about task and threading.

Comment: You can add this code into a new thread.  Is there a reason you don't want to use a new thread?

Comment: I read that link and it doesn't address my issue. The example given in the end assumes that the value is returned after the task finishes executing. In my case the other task would still continue working after it adds that value to the dictionary, and I mentioned that I do not want to complicate the code by doing inter thread/task communication between them. I just want to do everything by tasks as they are more efficient than threads, in my case I am expected to need potentially tens/hundreds of tasks, doing them all as separate threads and managing them myself would be so complicated.

Comment: @xander: You won't have multiple tasks on the same thread *at the same time*. (Well, I know of one very specialist reentrancy situation, but it wouldn't be the situation here.)